# Bundle getInt only return default value

Tags: java, android

I have a problem that is this code only return default value is -1. I tried to debug, it has value so i don't know why it alway return -1.

```
private static final String KEY_CATEGORY_ID = "category";
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
mCategoryId = bundle.getInt(KEY_CATEGORY_ID, -1);
```

This is my debug value:

```
bundle  Bundle  (id=830037735464)
Bundle[{category=2}]
```

Comment: Are you calling `setArguments()` on the fragment?

Comment: What happens if you do bundle.putInt("category", 5) just before your call to getInt()?

Comment: I called setArguments() and bundle.putInt("category", 2). My solution is clean and rebuild my project. Sometime i can understand my ADT.

Comment: @Nin_in_the_winD post the code where you set the argumesnt

Comment: I don;t know how to post code here:
`public static ListQuestFragment getInstance(int cateId) {
  ListQuestFragment fragment = new ListQuestFragment();
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putInt(KEY_CATEGORY_ID, cateId);
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  return fragment;
 }`

Comment: Mr.Dukeling: I just think that my algorithm went wrong so that i tag this tag. But now i agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your activity setArguments in this way

```
mFragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
extras.putInt("category", 10);
mFragment.setArguments(extras);
mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.profile_fragment, mFragment);
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In fragment get it in this way

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
catgory = bundle.getInt("category");
```